# Find last attempted instruction before exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to find out which was the last attempted instruction that triggered an exception, e.g. a TypeError.

Let's consider this example.

```
def test(value1, value2):
    print("Hello" + value1 + value2)
```

If this function is called with:

```
test("World!", 5)
test(5, "World!")
```

I will get a TypeError in both cases. However, in the first execution the last statement that wil be attempted (and triggers the error) is `"Hello" + value1`. In the second execution it would be `"Hello World!" + value2`. At least this is my assumption, that Python executes both separately, since they are "calls" to the add operator?

The error message will be the same both times though. Saying:

```
...
    print("Hallo" + value1 + value2)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Can I find out what the last executed statement was that triggered the TypeError?

Comment: do you try debug a code ?

Comment: No, it is part of attempting to build something like a dynamic type inferencer.

Comment: no you can't unless you resolve the adds separately

Comment: Doesn't Python at the Bytecode level execute both adds separately? And shouldn't the add that caused the error be last line (or maybe not show up at all) in the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot if operands are on the same line (there is no concept of "column" in python tracebacks). But you can workaround this by scattering the expression on more than one line:

```
def test(value1, value2):
    print(("Hello" + value1 +
    value2))
```

(note the added parentheses that avoid using `\` at the end of the line)

now with `test(5, "World!")` you get

```
  File "D:\module2.py", line 2, in test
    print(("Hello" + value1 +
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

and with `test("World!", 5)` you get

```
    test("World!", 5)
  File "D:\module2.py", line 3, in test
    value2))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

So depending on the error, you get line 2 or line 3.

Implicitly, the terse exception handling is encouraging you to avoid writing complex expressions in one go. Either decompose the computations, or use several lines to write the expression.

Comment: I see, this way I would have to parse the message.

Comment: I just managed to check, Python does execute the plus operations one after another, but as soon as the exception is thrown it seems the information how far we got seems to get lost.

Comment: yes, the plus operations are done left to right. And you don't need to parse the message if you use exception info. like `e.__traceback__.tb_next.tb_lineno` to get exception line in the function. The traceback object contains more structured info, so you don't have to parse the exception message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does not completely solve my problem but it is start.